# This password reset token is invalid laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Hi am Create new form for create user. Using custom route and controller.
But for reset password i am using default auth .
CUrrently i want to do , Send password reset(forgot) link to the user when admin created that user.
Currently I am sending mail after click on the mail link give error "This password reset token is invalid."

Below is my custom controller and mail function that i used.

```
public function contactSave(Request $request)
    {
        // $token = app(PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($request->mail);
        // $token = $request->_token;
        $password = Hash::make($request->name);
        $token = uniqid(base64_encode(Str::random(60)));
        $validate = $request->validate([
                        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
                        'email' => 'email',
                        'phone' => 'digits:10',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'country' => 'required',
                        'state' => 'required',
                        // 'comment' => 'required',
                        'organization' => 'required',
                        'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
                    ],
                    [
                'captcha.captcha' => 'Incorrect Captcha'
            ]
                );

        $user= new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;     
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->remember_token = Str::random(32);
        $user->save();


        if($user->id)
        {
            $CustomerContact= new CustomerContact;

            // $CustomerContact->name = $request->name;
            // $CustomerContact->email = $request->email;
            $CustomerContact->phone = $request->phone;
            $CustomerContact->address = $request->address;
            $CustomerContact->user_id = $user->id;
            $CustomerContact->country_id = $request->country;
            $CustomerContact->state_id = $request->state;
            $CustomerContact->comment = $request->comment;
            $CustomerContact->organization = $request->organization;
            $CustomerContact->captcha = $request->captcha;

            $CustomerContact->save();

            //New Mail
            DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        $tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $request->email)->first();

        $this->sendResetEmail($request->email, $token);
          
    }
        return redirect('contacts')->with('success', 'User created successfully.');

        
    }
```

this is mail function in that controller

```
private function sendResetEmail($email, $token)
    {
            //Retrieve the user from the database
            $user = DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->select('name', 'email')->first();
            //Generate, the password reset link. The token generated is embedded in the link
            $link = config('base_url') . 'password/reset/'. $token .'?email='.urlencode($user->email);

            $details = [
                'title' => 'Hi '.$user->name.'',
                'body' => 'Your account has been created successfully. Request you set your password with this link',
                // 'link' => URL::route('password/reset/'.$token)
                'url' => $link
            ];
           
            \Mail::to($email)->send(new \App\Mail\ContactMail($details));
            //Here send the link with CURL with an external email API 
           
}
```

Currently i have two issue i am getting this url into mail

(http://password/reset/VVdVMzZrMTZ3VXFITWhIWDVBak5SZk9CYUVuOEM1WWJPYzZBVEk4WHZ3eHpiR1dRYzhkZHFycWJrU1BI5fa7fa2d5dec8?email=praful06.rambade%40gmail.com)

if i add (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) then properly mail reset form open with that email id. But geeting this issue "This password reset token is invalid"

Please find attachement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yBA2.png)

Please help me if i am doing something wrong in this and guide me.

Comment: I think, you just need to change `$token` to `Hash::make($token)`  make sure you added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` on the top, let me know if it worked,

Comment: @sta if I do hash:make then error comes 404 | not found. Not working that.

Comment: You may use `$token = app(\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($user);` or `app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($user)`

Comment: @sta What will the $user exact? If you see my controller first line commented I think I used that but getting error. I want perfect solutions. From last 2-3 days I m stuck in that. Where I need to place that $token after user create or?